# Flutter show dialog show only if 2 showDialog() is called in one function

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a showDialog() function in flutter web, but it will only works this way (2 show dialog in one function), if I comment out the other one, the dialog will not show. I don't really understand why I need to put 2 showDialog() in order for it to show up. Here is the code:

```
onDeleteTap(String id) async {
print(id);
await showDialog<void>(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Hapus?'),
      content: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ListBody(
          children: <Widget>[
          ],
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
          child: Text('Batal'),
          onPressed: () {
          },
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 150.0,
          child: ErrorButton(
            text: "Hapus",
            onClick: () {
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);

await showDialog<void>(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Hapus?'),
      content: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ListBody(
          children: <Widget>[
          ],
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
          child: Text('Batal'),
          onPressed: () {
          },
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 150.0,
          child: ErrorButton(
            text: "Hapus",
            onClick: () {
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think before you are calling onDeleteTap you must be using navigator.pop(context). You can check by not showing any dialog to check if you are really poping a screen (If you are having a pop your current screen will close or you will have a black screen) or you can use the debbuger to check all the lines that passes before getting to this code.

Comment: I do have a dropdown button triggering the dialog, but there is no navigator.pop. I swapped out with a button and it works! Thanks!